# Any differences in structure between editions of Pynchon's V?

Tags: thomas-pynchon, v

In the Picador edition of Pynchon's *V*, there is a V of Vs on (pre) page 7, and each chapter title is structured as a V.

- Does the first edition also contain a V of Vs, and similarly structured chapter titles? *(Jonathan Cape in UK)*

*[... This use of the V (particularly the V of Vs) has always shaped my interpretation of the symbolism of V, and am now wondering if I should draw anything from these structural usages. ...]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first edition of V does indeed contain the V of Vs.

Not quite a proof, but here is a Pinterest image of what is claimed to be the Harmondsworth: Penguin, 1963 edition. This image can now be found on Google images.

[image]

I have also obtained the following image from an academic paper, [Poetics at the Interface : Patterns of Thought and Protocols of Reading in Studies of Thomas Pynchon’s V.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Poetics-at-the-Interface-%3A-Patterns-of-Thought-and-Bj%C3%B6rninen/ea717e80a2969e2fbe49cb7494675cd186caf422) by Samuli Björninen.

[image]

The real clincher is thanks to Gareth Rees who has found a J. Lippincott first edition, fourth impression (1963), on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/vnovel0000pync/page/n7/mode/2up), with the V of Vs. This image is identical to that of the previous.

Comment: Archive.org has a [J. Lippincott first edition, fourth impression](https://archive.org/details/vnovel0000pync/page/n7/mode/2up) (1963) with the V of Vs.

Comment: Well found, would you like to answer? I will withdraw mine.